# Enumeration of trichotomous relations

Tags: combinatorics, relations

I stuck with [Logic, Computation and Set Theory by T. Forster](http://www.pmfst.unist.hr/~milica/Teorija%20skupova/TSweb/N82_Ebook-Math%20-%202002%20-%20Forster,%20T.%20-%20Logic,%20Computation%20and%20Set%20Theory.pdf).
In Ex. 9 p. 14 it is stated that on the given set the amount of antisymmetrical relations equals to the amount of trichotomous ones.

However I cannot get the same amount. E.g. lets take $2$-element set $\{a, b\}$. There are $12$ antisymmetrical relations (total number of antisymmetrical relations is $2^n3^{(n^2-n)/2}$ for $n$-element domain). I was able to count only three trichotomous ones, viz. $\{(a,b)\}$, $\{(b,a)\}$ and $\{(a,a), (b,b)\}$.

Comment: Count the antisymmetric relations carefully. Are there really 12? What are they?

Comment: Dear @Tad, In case of $2$-element domain there are $16$ relations. Basically only $4$ relations will be non-antisymmetrical - namely those which have both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ pairs the rest of relations will be antisymmetrical. Hence $16 - 4 = 12$.

Comment: @Joriki has taken you where I wanted you to arrive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error in the text; your count of antisymmetric relations is correct. You counted one trichotomous relation too many; $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ isn't trichotomous. There are $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ trichotomous relations, since we must have exactly one of $(x,y)$ for all $x\ne y$, and we mustn't have $(x,x)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @joriki.  Could you clarify? Here's the definition of trichotomous relation: $\forall x \in X \, \forall y \in X \,   ((xRy \land \lnot (yRx) \land \lnot( x = y ))\lor$   $( \lnot(xRy) \land yRx \land \lnot( x = y)) \lor$  $( \lnot(xRy) \land \lnot(yRx) \land x = y)) $ It looks like {(a,a), (b,b)} relation satisfies the third part of condition.

Comment: @Artem: For $x=y=a$ (and also for $x=y=b$), the third condition doesn't hold. It reads $¬(aRa)∧¬(aRa)∧a=a))$, which is false since $aRa$ is true. A trichotomy is irreflexive.